# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't start anymore but only boots to grub terminal after system froze during sudo apt upgrade

Tags: grub2, xubuntu

Yesterday I wanted to update my 16.04 Xubuntu. When I ran sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade (system wasn't able to complete the upgrade process), the system froze and I had to restart by force.

But now I cannot even start the system anymore. After each reboot, only the grub terminal is shown. I also cannot access the grub menu by pressing ESC key (my system is UEFI).

Do you have any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: Well, my system cannot boot into ubuntu anymore. I am stuck at the terminal, I am not sure if this truly is a duplicate. But I really have to test with boot-repair and see if it helps.

Comment: Xubuntu LTS is only supported for 3 years rather than 5 years.  You need to use a supported version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from a LiveCD, and then there are a number of different methods you can use to troubleshoot and repair your boot loader.

I've never used it, but [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is one such method, and looks promising.

Comment: Thanks buddy, and I will try it out. I will post later about whether I was able to solve this problem by using LiveCD and Boot-repair tool.

Comment: Thanks, this truly saved my day!